# Disable parts of the touch screen in android

Tags: android, andengine, touchscreen

So I was trying to disable the screen for an app I am making for a brief period using this

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent pMotioneEvent) {
        if(pMotioneEvent.getY() < TestSprite.getY()){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;    
        }           
}
```

but this seems to have no effect. I read around and it seems like in general its a bad idea to disable the touch screen, but I'm still curious to know if there is a way.
Thanks

Comment: It is a bad idea because you're taking control away from the users that may affect other parts of the phone (depends what your app is). As a workaround, could you not put an invisible Rectangle (or some control) over the areas which you don't want enabled. This way, that control will absorb the event, giving the illusion that the touch screen doesn't work in that section?

Comment: I've tried that but when I touch a location all objects at that location are touched, regardless of visibility(or Z index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

[requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for touchevents in a certain area of your screen, you might want to put this in a View and set a touchEvent Listener to it.